# What is the getdate() equivalent for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a query to update and set some values in some fields.

Obut Now I need to update these field and in adition, I need to set `DateOfModification` to the current date and time.

What is the equivalent to GETDATE() from sql server to use in a $set?

I tried this:

```
db.col.updateMany({
     "field.field":"zzzzzzzz" 
},{$set:{
        "field2" : {
        "field3" : ObjectId("5d4dc2c2b3e6de001b934ec6"), 
        "field4" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "DateOfModification: "$$NOW"
    }
}})
```

but It seems the $$NOW only works with mongoDB 4.2 and I'm still using 4.0

Thanks

Edit:

I tried $currentDate but still getting errors:

```
db.testeDBA.update(
        {},
          {$set: {"item":"anything",$currentDate: {"modifiedOn":true}}      
        })
```

> 'The dollar ($) prefixed field '$currentDate' in
> '$currentDate' is not valid for storage.+

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19612338/inserting-the-current-datetime-in-mongodb

Comment: `$$NOW` is available only in [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/index.html#aggregation-variables), not in simple `updateMany`. Try `new Date()` or `ISODate()`. You can use aggregation pipelines in `updateMany`, however it also requires MongoDB 4.2 or newer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
db.testDBA.updateOne(
   {},
   {
     $currentDate: {
        modifiedOn:true
     },
     $set: {
        "item":"anything"
     }
   })
```

I inserted a new document and updated it. It worked.

[image]

If I run this code again, the document will be updated like this

[image]

Comment: it worked. thanks